# PostgreSQL. Exclude rows if the value in some column is present two or more times

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a 'codes' table:

```
+---------+---------+
| numbers | letters |
+=========+=========+
| 1       | a       |
+---------+---------+
| 2       | b       |
+---------+---------+
| 3       | a       |
+---------+---------+
| 4       | c       |
+---------+---------+
| 5       | a       |
+---------+---------+
| 6       | b       |
+---------+---------+
```

Values in the 'numbers' column are unique (like 'id').

There is a need to exclude rows if the 'letter' value is present two and more times.

The result should be the following:

```
+---------+---------+
| numbers | letters |
+=========+=========+
| 4       | c       |
+---------+---------+
```

How can I get the query for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
select min(number), letter
from codes
group by letter
having count(*) = 1;
```

If the numbers are guaranteed to be unique, then `not exists` might be the fastest solution:

```
select c.*
from codes c
where not exists (select 1
                  from codes c2
                  where c2.letter = c.letter and c2.number <> c.number
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks, both ways work fine with the provided table.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT (array_agg(numbers))[1] AS "numbers", letters
FROM tab
GROUP BY letters
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

There are many other ways.

Edit: Gordon's solution is much simpler.

Comment: The benefit of this answer is that `ARRAY_AGG()` works with things like UUID columns, whereas `MIN()` and `MAX()` won't.